# Prevent ScrollView from scrolling to top

Tags: android, scrollview

I've a `ScrollView`, inside that there are few views one of them is a `TextView`. I'm pragmatically  setting current time to the `TextView`. Therefore `TextView` updates every second. Now when I over scroll `ScrollView`, the ScrollView moves to top. I guess its losing touch when `TextView` updates.

**So how can I prevent ScrollView to move to top?**

Answer (score 3):

That's your friend:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Set this attribute to the Elements INSIDE of the ScrollView.

But since this removes the focusability of the elements you won't be able to edit any inputs like EditText etc.

In this case you could "prevent" the ScrollView from scrolling to the current focus (it does not scroll "to the top") by ensuring the focus to be at the position I like.

To give an example: 
I've got a ScrollView with a TableView inside and a CheckBox in each row of the table. When I check one of them, the color of the current row is to be changed. But: the moment I set the color, the ScrollView scrolls to the focus.
So I set the focus to the ckeckbox I just clicked before I change the color:

```
 // enable focusability if necessary:
    // cbOK.setFocusable(true);
    // cbOK.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    cbOK.requestFocus();
    row.setBackgroundColor(....);
```

Comment: This post helped me tremendously.  You have no idea.  Thanks!